# save the checked items in checkbox to session

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Need help. I want to save the items that are check in my checkbox to a Session.

What I'm doing is get the value of the items that are checked and store it in an array. Then I will assign that value as Session Name and assign a value of 1 to the session.

This is the code that I'm using but it only gets the first item that is checked.

```
dim  checkboxList
checkboxList = request.Form("schedule")
checkboxList = split(checkboxList, ",")

for each i in checkboxList
    Session(i) = 1
next
```

for example If I check A and B on my Checkbox I should get

Session("A")=1 and Session("B")=1

but the only thing i'm getting is Session("A")=1

I tried checking if I'm getting the right item on the my Array by Using this code and the data is correct.

```
dim  checkboxList
checkboxList = request.Form("schedule")
checkboxList = split(checkboxList, ",")

for each i in checkboxList
    response.write(i)
next
```

Here is my Html Code.

```
<form class="well" method="post" action="applicationSave.asp">
 <div class="controls">
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="onShifts" name="schedule" value="onShifts" <% if Session("onShifts") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> On Shifts?<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="nightShifts" name="schedule" value="nightShifts" <% if Session("nightShifts") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Night Shifts?<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="partTime" name="schedule" value="partTime" <% if Session("partTime") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Part Time?<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="fullTime" name="schedule" value="fullTime" <% if Session("fullTime") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Full Time<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="holidays" name="schedule" value="holidays" <% if Session("holidays") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Holidays/Sundays?<br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="projectBasis" name="schedule" value="projectBasis" <% if Session("projectBasis") = 1 then response.Write("checked") end if %> /> Project Basis
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: I can only assign a value of 1 to the first item that is checked. for example if I check A,B,C on my checkbox I should get the following.

Session("A")=1
Session("B")=1
Session)"C")=1

but i only get the first one.

Comment: Please post the HTML as well, that will be necessary to give a correct answer

Comment: Ok sir. It seems that I'm getting the correct value that I want by using session.content but It's not showing on my html page. I updated my update. I added the html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because values delimited with ", " (comma-space), instead "," only.
So, before working with array make "trimming" items:

```
Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(checkboxList)
checkboxList(i) = Trim(checlboxList(i))
Next
```

Another way - write `Session(Trim(i)) = 1` in for statement.

BTW: Commonly, your code is unsafe. E.g, you have some session bool variable `Session("IsAuthorized")`. Visitor can send request to your .asp file with value `schedule=IsAuthorized`...